# Is it normal that it takes 3 minutes to restart nodemon due to changes?

Tags: nodemon, nuxt.js, adonis.js

It takes more than 3 min to restart nodemon. I think it is too long.

I use adonisjs + nuxt (from https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app).

Under dev mode(I ran "npm run dev"),

I have some server side files that is controllers or models(red area in below attatched image),

and I have also client side files that is Vue page files(yellow area in below attatched image).

[image]

When I change any client side files, for example resources/pages/index.vue, nodemon is restarting automatically. And it takes less than 5 sec. It's cool.

[image]

But When I change any server side files, for example Controllers/Http/MenuController.js, nodemon is restarting automatically too. But it takes more than 3 min!

[image]

I am a newby at nodejs. So I dont know this is normal or abnormal.
I spend more than 3 min every time I change server side code. I think this is too inefficient.

Please let me know how to fix this or why it takes more than 3 min.

Comment: This is not related to AdonisJs, but that depends on the quantity of JS code you have on the client side (Nuxt uses a bunch of tools under the hood)